# Creating a spell checking function in python

Tags: python, function

So, I am new to python and currently leading how to program basic functions with it. I have be asked to make a function which spell checks a word against the known correct spelling.

If the word is correct the function returns "correct", if there 2 or less mistakes it returns "almost" and if 3 or more mistakes are present the function returns "wrong". So for example if the function if of the formation 
 `spell(correct, guess)`
`spell('hello', hello')` would return 'correct', `spell('hello','nello')` would return 'almost', and `spell('hello','hejje')` would return 'wrong'.

My code for this is:

```
def spell(correct, guess):
    answer=list(guess)
    right=list(correct)
    w=0

    for i in answer and right:
        if answer[i]==right[i]:
            w=w
        else:
            w=w+1
    if w==0:
        print("correct")
    elif w==1 or w==2:
        print("Almost")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
```

I trying to define the function by adding up the number of difference between the two lists. But I keep getting the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" and I don't know another way of setting up the problem. I want to know the best way to approach coding this so I can try and attempt my code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues

1)
When you say

```py
for i in answer and right:
```

the code is only iterating through `right`.  You need to be unambiguous about which list you're iterating through.  The solution to this is related to the second issue.

2)
Iterating through a list of strings will return strings

Saying

```py
a = ["b", "c", "d"]
for i in a:
    print(a[i])
```

does not make sense.  `a[i]` means the i^th element of `a`, but in this case, `i` is literally the strings you're iterating through.  It's equivalent to saying `a["b"]`

Instead, you should be iterating through the indices of the two lists:

```py
for i in range(len(answer)):
    if answer[i] == right[i]:
        etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something like `word1 = 'hello'` and `word2 = 'nello'`, then you can do this:

```py
sum(word1[i] != word2[i] for i in range(min(len(word1), len(word2))))
```

The reason yours isn't working is because of how you are using the for loop:

```py
for i in answer and right:
```

if `answer` is `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, then `i` is going to be each character within that list. As long as what evaluates to `right` is `True` and because `right` is a non-empty list, it will. So `i` is going to be each character in `'hello'`, which is why you are getting your error.

EDIT: A simpler version of your for loop:

```py
for i in range(len(answer)):
    if answer[i] != right[i]:
        w = w + 1
```

Comment: So I would swap my line of answer[i]=right[i] for this line?

Comment: @H.Linkhorn I added a version of your for loop at the end. You were close, you just need to iterate over the indices to access the strings by index.